# "Missing number, treated as zero" error

Tags: page-numbering

I'm trying to compile an example from a tutorial, but there's an error that I cannot fix.
My code is the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Titulo}
\author{Example}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\newpage
\pagenumbering{Arabic}
\section{Section}
Hello world
\subsection{Subsection}
Structuring a document is easy
\end{document}
```

Then, when running the code the error: `"Missing number, treated as zero, <to be read again>"\hfil \end{document}"` appears.

Comment: change `\pagenumbering{Arabic}` by  `\pagenumbering{arabic}`

Comment: @flav Please do it. I had to answer myself but you were the brilliant one!

Comment: In fact, when the solution is simple enough, TeX.SX recommend to not write an answer but just post a comment. You also can upvote the comment.

Answer (score 2):

Solution posted by [flav](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/71988/flav)

change `\pagenumbering{Arabic}` by `\pagenumbering{arabic}`